# Unable to create events for different user in Google calendar

Tags: php, api, calendar, google-calendar-api, refresh-token

**Hi everyone.
I hope you all are doing well.**

I know this question has been asked many times but non of the solutions provided there worked for me.

I am implementing google calendar API in custom PHP. I have followed the official documentation provided by Google. I have been able to create and get events for a specific user.

My original goal was to allow every user to get, create, update and delete Events on their own calendar.

Here's what I have been doing in the code.

***This is calendarSetting.php file.***

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}
?>
```

***This is createCalendar.php file***

```
<?php

  require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
  include('calendarSetting.php');
  session_start();
  $appointment_id = $_SESSION['appointment_id'];
  $patient_fname = $_SESSION['patient_fname'];
  $patient_lname = $_SESSION['patient_lname'];
  $patient_phone = $_SESSION['patient_phone'];
  $schedule = $_SESSION['appointment_date'];
  $start_date = $_SESSION['start'];
  $end_date = $_SESSION['end'];
 
    $client = getClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
        'summary' => $patient_fname . ' ' . $patient_lname,
        'description' => $patient_fname . ' ' . ' ' . $patient_lname . ' ' . $patient_phone ,
        
        'start' => array(
          'dateTime' => $start_date.':00+05:00',
          'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        ),
        'end' => array(
          'dateTime' => $end_date.':00+05:00',
          'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        ),
        'recurrence' => array(
          'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1'
        ),
        'attendees' => array(
          array('email' => 'abc1211@gmail.com')
        )
         
        
      ));
    
      $calendarId = 'user876@gmail.com';
      $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
    printf('Event created');
    header('location: Doctor');


?>
```

This is perfectly working for the user where  **$calendarId = 'user876@gmail.com';**. but if I change the user it gives me an error.

> **Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "errors":
> [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "Not Found" }
> ], "code": 404, "message": "Not Found" } } in
> F:\xampp\htdocs\bupa1\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Http\REST.php:128
> Stack trace: #0
> F:\xampp\htdocs\bupa1\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Http\REST.php(103):
> Google\Http\REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response),
> Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1 [internal
> function]: Google\Http\REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client),
> Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2
> F:\xampp\htdocs\bupa1\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Task\Runner.php(182):
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3
> F:\xampp\htdocs\bupa1\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Http\REST.php(66):
> Google\Task\Runner->run() #4
> F:\xampp\htdocs\bupa1\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Client.php(898):
> Google\Http\REST::execute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client),
> Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...', Array, NULL) #5
> F:\x in
> F:\xampp\htdocs\bupa1\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Http\REST.php on
> line 128**

I have been trying to figure out why is this happening. so far what I found is that each time when i send a request to google to create the event my access token in the **calendarSetting.php file** isn't refreshing.

Now I got stuck on how can I get the refresh token so that a new user could also create events.

If anybody could help to figure this out I'll be very grateful.

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think its the refresh token?   Try doing a a calendar.get on abc1211@gmail.com looks to me like you dont have access to that calendar.   How exactly are you changing user?

Comment: Upcoming events:
Event id: oqter2kiptconjh5nlkm0auldc_20210622T200300Z Event date= 2021-06-20 Event Title = Potage D- Ace Start date= 2021-06-23T01:03:00+05:00 End date= 2021-06-23T01:04:00+05:00
Event id: c1vqmlbceb4q82eir3da15niko_20210624T065500Z Event date= 2021-06-20 Event Title = Patient Test for Encryption Start date= 2021-06-24T11:55:00+05:00 End date= 2021-06-24T11:56:00+05:00

Comment: Actually, abc1211@gmail.com is the email address of the attendee. Currently, the user who is creating the event is user876@gmail.com I have shared the list of events that I have created by user876@gmail.com.

Comment: The reason I think that it's the refresh token is that I have echoed the token and refresh token, its value was the same for every user from whom I wanted to create an event.

Comment: Therefore whenever I changed the user I deleted the token.json file from the root directory and then I send a request to create an event on google calendar. First, it redirected me to google authentication and after the successful authentication token.json file was created again in the root directory. and my request to create an event got successful as well.

Comment: But this can't possibly be a solution because every time I change the email address in calendarid I also have to delete the token.json file so that on request to create an event I have to complete authentication which creates a new token.json file in order to successfully create events for the user.

Comment: I hope I didn't cause more confusion :(

Comment: name the tokenPath  after each user so each user has their own credentials file.  or if this is web based you should be using session vars.

Comment: Can you clarify that you want to have this to be a web page where users visit and are able to use your app to manage their calendar?

Comment: yeah exactly I'm doing it for a web page.

Comment: @DaImTo Actually i want to be saved from creating credential file for each user. Also there are two files, one is client_secret.json file that has client_id, and client_secret and the other is token.json file that has access token and the refresh token. Can you guide me which credential file are you referring to. I'm sorry again if i sound too senseless. I'm in fact a rookie.

Comment: by using token.json you are creating a single user system.  Its normally only used for backend applications.

Answer (score 1):

What you have right now will end up being a single user system.  If the file exists then no one else will need to login.   If you start deleting that file then what about if user one is still using the system they will then be reading data using user twos token from the file.

If this is a web app you should be using session vars.

## [oauth2callback.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/oauth2callback.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Oauth2Authentication.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = buildClient();
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client = buildClient();
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange the authencation code for a refresh token and access token.
    // Add access token and refresh token to seession.
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();    
    //Redirect back to main script
    $redirect_uri = str_replace("oauth2callback.php",$_SESSION['mainScript'],$client->getRedirectUri());    
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

## [Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

You should check the full link for all the code in this file.  Notice how it stores the users tokens in the session vars so each user has its own tokens stored in its browser.

```
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {
        
        $client = buildClient();
        
        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }
        
        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            
            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 
            
            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah you are totally right about that, if i delete the file it will cause trouble for other users. Using session variable does seems working in this case. I need to try this out. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: remember to accept the anwser if it helped.  If you have any issues open a new question with your new code and i should spot it.

Comment: yeah, sure thing.

Comment: so i have used session variables. I am getting the code from url every time when the user get authenticated from the google. But then when it redirects to the oauth2callback.php it has started to give another error.

Comment: $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);       $token = $client->getAccessToken();

Comment: when i vardump the  $token it is giving me null.

Comment: Open a new question and post your code there.